# Full featured example application written in Cocoa (Mac desktop)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a fully featured cocoa sample application you can recommend I look at?

I've seen the sample's on the developer.apple.com website, but they are usually focused on a single feature.

Looking for something that is not so simple, and is written with clean code etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Well-written Open Source Cocoa apps to learn from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193142/well-written-open-source-cocoa-apps-to-learn-from)

Answer (score 3):

There are tons of them out there, but they are definitely hard to find. Here's a list of ones I can think of off the top of my head. Although do note that these will probably look very overwhelming if you're just starting with OS X development (sorry but I don't have enough reputation to make these all actual links).

[QuickSilver](https://github.com/quicksilver/Quicksilver) is a very complicated application launcher that has recently started being under active development again.

[nvALT](https://github.com/ttscoff/nv) is a note taking application that syncs with SimpleNote

[QuickCursor](https://github.com/jessegrosjean/quickcursor/) is a small menu bar utility for opening copied text in different editors.

[Kod](https://github.com/rsms/kod/) which is an unfinished programmers text editor. Even being only half way completed (it is no longer under active development) it's still a great app.

[Colloquy](http://colloquy.info/project/wiki/Source%20Code) which is a IRC application.

[Chuck](https://github.com/msanders/Chuck) is a very minimal application launcher.

[Adium](http://trac.adium.im/wiki/GettingNewestAdiumSource) (as mentioned by Rob) is an IM application with a ridiculous amount of features.

Answer (score 2):

http://cocoadev.com/wiki/CocoaOpen has a list, of which at least Adium and MacHg look decent.